# Azure Function "dotnet-isolated" .Net 6 Could not find a part of the path 'C:\home\LogFiles\application\functions\function\TestOutOfProc'

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0

In VS 2022 .net 6
When I deploy to Azure a .net 6 in process vanila function I can test it in the portal and it works from the Azure URL.
When I do the same with "dotnet-isolated" out of process vanila function, it tells me:

```
Editing .NET 5 Function Apps is not supported in the Azure portal. Use your local development environment to edit this function.
```

Attaching a Debugger from the "Publish" page, shows the breaking point as not reachable and posting in Postman does not break there.

How can I debug and test in Azure then?
Thanks

Comment: You can refer to [Upgrade of Visual Studio or .NET SDK from earlier builds can result in a bad PATH configuration on Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/known-issues.md#2-upgrade-of-visual-studio-or-net-sdk-from-earlier-builds-can-result-in-a-bad-path-configuration-on-windows)

Comment: You can open an issue on GitHub: [azure-functions-dotnet-worker](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues)

Answer (score -1):

> Editing .NET 5 Function Apps is not supported in the Azure portal. Use your local development environment to edit this function.

In general you receive this error might be because of the following any of the reasons:

1. This behaviour of modifying functions via the Azure portal is not supported by every combination (SKU, language, operating system).Only that combination is supported to be produced in Azure Portal if you see 'Develop in portal' option in a Development environment.
2. It's possible that external editing was Disabled.

   **FIX:** We may immediately click the "Read/Write" option to make the Function App editable and the "Read Only" button to make it read-only in the "Function app settings" of the Function App on the Azure portal. For further information, please view the picture below.
   [image]
3. Settings from the Configuration settings are missing.

   **FIX:** Set [WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentazurefileconnectionstring) and [WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentshare) values with your connection string and function name from Configuration settings.

You may also try making modifications to your function app locally, then publishing the dotnet-isolated out of process vanila function and debugging it like you did with .net 6 in process vanila.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Portal editing is disabled-1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/540309/azure-function-portal-editing-is-disabled.html)
2. [Portal editing is disabled-2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/583135/portal-editing-is-disabled.html?childToView=583359#answer-583359)
3. [Configure function app settings in Azure Functions | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal)